# Can't see images Symfony 1.4.18

Tags: apache2, symfony-1.4, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to set up Symfony 1.4.18 in a Linux environment. I'm running Ubuntu 12.04LTS.

The issue is that once I get to the Symfony setup page where you should see "Symfony Project Created" graphically, all I get is it in text form.

For some reason it is not accessing the /sf folder. I've added in the alias, but it still isn't rendering correctly. This is the info I added to the end of the httpd.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/sfproject/web"
DirectoryIndex index.php
<Directory "/var/www/sfproject/web">
  AllowOverride All
  Allow from All
</Directory>

Alias /sf /var/www/sfproject/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf
<Directory "/var/www/sfproject/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf">
  AllowOverride All
  Allow from All
</Directory>
```

As you can see, I modified the path to reflect the way my system is set up. var/www is my root web folder; I based everything off of that.

When I access the page in my browser I type "http://localhost/sfproject/web/index.php", not "http://localhost:8080/index.php/" as per the Symfony instructions. Perhaps this will shed some light on the issue.

Thanks for the help, and God Bless! :)

Comment: Why don't you want to access the page with `http://localhost:8080/index.php/` as you setup your virtualhost to do so?

Answer (score 0):

If you are accessing the code with h t t p://localhost/sfproject/web/index.php, I'm sure that all this apache configuration you have write is not working.

Here you have some instructions to apache2-symfony working:

- delete this configuration you have added (that's not working)
- define some test-domain four you app (like "my_test")
- create a file at /etc/apache2/sites-available, for example: "my_test_apache_config", or simply "my_test"

  ```
          <VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost        
            ServerName my_test  
            # this will be your app url, like http://my_test/

            DocumentRoot /var/www/sfproject/web  
            # point to the symfony project web folder

            DirectoryIndex index.php     

            <Directory "/var/www/sfproject/web" > 
            # point to the symfony project web folder
                  AllowOverride All
                  Allow from All
            </Directory>

            Alias /sf /var/www/sfproject/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf  
            # path for default images

            <Directory "/var/www/sfproject/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf" > 
            # path for default images
                  AllowOverride All
                  Allow from All
           </Directory>

            # I recommend you to have some special log for every site
            ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/my_test_error.log   
            LogLevel warn   # idem
            CustomLog /var/log/apache2/my_test_access.log combined

          </VirtualHost>
  ```
- run "sudo a2ensite my_test"
- run "sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart"
- edit (as root) /etc/hosts and add one entry for your development domain pointing to localhost, like:

  127.0.0.1       my_test
- restart your browser
- browse to h t t p ://my_test/index.php

And that's all. This maybe looks heavy, but it's not. 
If some day you wish to take down your site locally, just run:
"sudo a2dissite my_test"